# Проверка на изменение $location.path()

Tags: angularjs, phonegap, angular-routing, ionic

Каким образом можно проверить изменение в $location.path()?

Начну с кода:

```
if ($location.path() === '/main/tips' || $location.path() === '/main/diseases' || $location.path() === '/main/nouseful'){
        console.log('Show');
    } else {
        console.log('Hide');
    }
```

Срабатывает лишь один раз, а нужно что бы при каждом изменении `$location.path()`. Этот код находится в контроллере, который завязан на теге body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы используете ngRoute, Вы можете использовать событие  $routeChangeSuccess(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
   console.log('location', $location.path());
   // Ваша логика
});
```

Пример: http://plnkr.co/edit/YMOax7Ej3wG5Sr2AvMBE